# CSS: display:inline does not seems to work on IE

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I use CSS to make a unordered list `ul` to be displayed horizontally like this

```
 <div id="header">
     <ul>
        <li class="header-li">....</li>
        <li class="header-li" style="width: 200px; display: inline-block;">
                            ...                                
        </li>                            

     </ul>
 </div>
```

here is my css

```
#header
{ 
    height: 30px;
    width: 985px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}

.header-li{
    display: inline;    
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

`display:inline` is help display my list horizontally, this work on FF, Safari and Chrome but does not work on IE8. Help please here is some screen shot show the different between Firefox look and IE look

[image: FireFox, Chrome and Safari Look][image: IE Look]

Comment: Harry, I may be wrong but could you not accomplish this with a simple set of floated divs?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the issue Harry? The screen shot you have attached isn't very clear. Any chance of attaching a more clear image? See example on jsfiddle.net to see working example of your above code: http://jsfiddle.net/j8pba/

Comment: @sscirrus: you are right, and that was exactly what I did. Work out great. Thank you +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you want to use `float:left` as opposed to `display:inline` for the better support